# differentiability and closed interval

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is a real-valued differentiable function in $[a,b]$, is it true that $f'$ maps $[a,b]$ into a closed interval? Here $f'$ means first derivative of function $f$.

I tried to use DARBOUX theorem but it is not helpful.

Comment: How do you define $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$?

Answer (score 4):

The image of $f'$ need not be a closed interval. As an example, consider

$$g(t) = \begin{cases}e^{-\lvert t\rvert}\sin \frac1t &, t \neq 0\\ 0 &, t = 0\end{cases}$$

and

$$f(x) := \int_0^x g(t)\,dt.$$

It is immediate that $f'(x) = g(x)$ for $x \neq 0$. It is less evident, but can be verified by a little computation (see below), that $f$ is also differentiable at $x = 0$ with $f'(0) = 0$. Consequently, $f'([a,\,b]) = (-1,\,1)$ for all intervals with $a < 0 < b$.

---

To compute $f'(0)$, we rewrite the integral to get something easier to handle,

$$f(x) = \underbrace{\int_0^x \sin \frac1t\,dt}_{a(x)} - \underbrace{\int_0^x (1 - e^{-\lvert t\rvert})\sin \frac1t\, dt}_{b(x)}.$$

By symmetry ($g$ is an odd function, hence $f$ is even), we need only consider $x > 0$. $b(x)$ is very simple to treat:

$$\lvert b(x)\rvert \leqslant \int_0^x \left\lvert (1-e^{-t})\sin \frac1t\right\rvert \, dt \leqslant \int_0^x \lvert 1-e^{-t}\rvert\,dt \leqslant \int_0^x t\,dt = \frac{x^2}{2},$$

thus $\frac{b(x)-b(0)}{x} \leqslant \frac{x}{2} \to 0$.

For $a(x)$, we substitute $u = 1/t$ and obtain

$$\begin{align}
a(x) &= \int_0^x \sin \frac1t\,dt\\
&= \int_{1/x}^\infty \frac{\sin u}{u^2}\, du\\
&= \left[\frac{-\cos u}{u^2}\right]_{1/x}^\infty - 2\int_{1/x}^\infty \frac{\cos u}{u^3}\,du\\
&= x^2\cos \frac1x - 2\int_{1/x}^\infty \frac{\cos u}{u^3}\,du.
\end{align}$$

The integral can be estimated

$$2\left\lvert \int_{1/x}^\infty \frac{\cos u}{u^3}\,du\right\rvert \leqslant \int_{1/x}^\infty \frac{2}{u^3}\,du = x^2$$

and therefore

$$\left\lvert \frac{a(x)-a(0)}{x}\right\rvert \leqslant 2x,$$

which, together with the estimate for $b$ yields

$$\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right\rvert \leqslant \frac52 x.$$

Comment: Hi @Daniel can I ask you how would you prove that $f'(0)=0$? For $h>0$, I tought to treat separately $\frac{1}{h}\int _0 ^\delta g$ and $\frac{1}{h}\int _\delta ^h g$, but while I see how to make the first small, I can't get rid of the second. Also, how did such a function occur to you, if I may?

Comment: I'll add the proof of $f'(0) = 0$, will take a bit. As for how it occurred, $\sin (1/x)$ is a standard example of weird things, so I looked around that a bit. It's just the old "if you have the right idea, it works out easily, if not, you're stumped". Sometimes it works out, other times you stay silent.

Answer (score 2):

More easily let us consider a constant function on a closed interval. Its derivative will be $\{0\}$, which is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ but not a closed interval. So the answer.

Comment: How is this not a closed interval?

Comment: $\{0\}$ is a degenerate closed interval. Thank you mrf.